# How long does it take for a manuscript to be given a reference number?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, editors

I have submitted my manuscript to a journal over 37 days and the status remains "Manuscript Submitted". The email says "Your manuscript will be given a reference number once an Editor has been assigned". May I know how long normally it takes for a manuscript to be assigned to editors? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the journal (area and type)!
For example, some colleagues waiting for 3 years for an answer from editors.

Comment: Thanks, Bruna for your reply. Three years for an answer!!! That's torture!